# Docker error: too many open files

Tags: docker

I got that error message when creating container.

```
Error response from daemon: too many open files
```

But  I couldn't find any information about that error.
(I saw https://github.com/docker/libcontainer/issues/211, but that was not the same problem of it.)
Is there anyone who knows about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Default limit of number of open files is 1024. You can increase it in two ways:

1. Run the container with `--ulimit` parameter:

   ```
   docker run --ulimit nofile=5000:5000 <image-tag>
   ```
2. Run the container with `--privileged` mode and execute `ulimit -n 5000`.

You can find more information [here](http://mtyurt.net/2017/04/06/docker-how-to-increase-number-of-open-files-limit/).

Answer (score 3):

It's more convenient to set the ulimit inside the docker systemD service

Modify `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_ADD_RUNTIMES --default-ulimit nofile=65535:65535
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this issue is not better solved already, I develop with Docker alot on my Mac so Docker is running in a tiny VM.  I came across this issue about 2 years ago and it took me ages to find a work around and I hit the issue all the time.  I forget where I found this "fix" but when ever I reboot my Mac I have to run this in order for my containers not to complain about "too many open files" - if I forget to run this then its not always obvious what the issue is either, sure a container will log the error somewhere but when you have dozens of containers running with detailed logging its difficult to track - anyway, the script is

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -ti --privileged centos sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192
```