# nginx + uwsgi running on Amazon ECS returns socket: Too many open files (24) ( changing Ulimit did not help )

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi, amazon-ecs, apachebench

I have a UWSGI running behind Nginx proxy server. I tried to benchmark my backend instance using Apache bench. At one point in time, I get `Too many open files (24)` error when I run the command `ab -c 1100 -n 2000 https://example.com/test`.

I changed the ulimits of my ECS Instance as well as the docker containers and confirmed it by typing `ulimit -n` which returns `100000`  in both the locations.

I cross checked the Individual NGINX, Uwsgi processes limits by opening the `/proc/PID` where the `Max open files` is set to 100000.

The `worker_connections` and `worker_rlimit_nofile` parameters in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` are also set to highest limit possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29403185/5030709 if you are running nginx and uwsgi as docker containers.