# Docker: too many open files

Tags: docker

I have Docker installed via Snap on Ubuntu 20.04. From time to time, Portainer (which I'm using as graphical UI to manage the containers) stops responding - in the sense, the UI accepts interaction, but the list of containers won't load, or the list of volumes, I won't be able to set up a new container, etc.

When I ran `snap logs docker` just now, I got the following:

```
2022-10-07T09:38:59+03:00 docker.dockerd[770]: time="2022-10-07T09:38:59.500434820+03:00" level=error msg="Error replicating health state for container 5e7ed995ca45945035048596539293a9bb11ee0b4e30e7c4956eec953077806b: open /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/5e7ed995ca45945035048596539293a9bb11ee0b4e30e7c4956eec953077806b/.tmp-config.v2.json632473701: too many open files"
2022-10-07T09:38:59+03:00 docker.dockerd[770]: time="2022-10-07T09:38:59.542152208+03:00" level=error msg="Error replicating health state for container f876ad961153cbd2815cc7715983987bc072c631a378cf3d2ba7e248aae27423: open /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/f876ad961153cbd2815cc7715983987bc072c631a378cf3d2ba7e248aae27423/.tmp-config.v2.json471368832: too many open files"
2022-10-07T09:38:59+03:00 docker.dockerd[770]: time="2022-10-07T09:38:59.542155861+03:00" level=error msg="Error replicating health state for container dabe3abe216046ef5b84e3169f7faf90b6e3050cef75a8ca23e940e516ecff20: open /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/dabe3abe216046ef5b84e3169f7faf90b6e3050cef75a8ca23e940e516ecff20/.tmp-config.v2.json801890271: too many open files"
2022-10-07T09:39:00+03:00 dockerd[770]: http: Accept error: accept unix /var/run/docker.sock: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

2022-10-07T09:39:01+03:00 dockerd[770]: http: Accept error: accept unix /var/run/docker.sock: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

2022-10-07T09:39:02+03:00 dockerd[770]: http: Accept error: accept unix /var/run/docker.sock: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

2022-10-07T09:39:02+03:00 docker.dockerd[770]: time="2022-10-07T09:39:02.822036736+03:00" level=error msg="Error replicating health state for container 98bee8456d114bff5ee423f46e7e0892dfdf5af694c8edc522841ce5e5976b1f: open /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/98bee8456d114bff5ee423f46e7e0892dfdf5af694c8edc522841ce5e5976b1f/.tmp-config.v2.json624827314: too many open files"
2022-10-07T09:39:03+03:00 dockerd[770]: http: Accept error: accept unix /var/run/docker.sock: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

2022-10-07T09:39:04+03:00 dockerd[770]: http: Accept error: accept unix /var/run/docker.sock: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
```

Could you help me figure out what's causing this and how to avoid it in the future, please?

Thank you!

**EDIT (31 Oct):** the same problem has been occurring numerous times since I last wrote this post. I've tried the suggestions by IamK below, but they don't seem to work.

More specifically, even though I edited `etc/sysctl.conf`, the current soft and hard limits remain 1024 and 1048576, respectively.

I'd grealy appreciate further help. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker error: too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403185/docker-error-too-many-open-files)

Comment: I saw this, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case, because - as I said, Docker is installed via Snap. Where could I find some instructions how to apply this setting?

Comment: You can pass the limit as argument while running the container. (that method is above), or you can modify your host's limit.

Comment: I have a lot of containers and I'm not sure which one(s) is causing this issue. So I'd rather modify the host's limit. Any idea how to do this with Snap?

Comment: you can check the current limits with `ulimit -Sn` (soft limit), `ulimit -Hn` (hard limit), increase the limit for the current session (wont survive a reboot) `ulimit -n 100000`, to increase system-wide edit: `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add `fs.file-max = 2097152` save the file and `sysctl -p` (loads settings to the kernel from the sysctl.conf)

Comment: Thank you, @C1sc0! I've done all this, rebooted the machine and will wait and see if the problem appears again.

Comment: Hello again. I ran into the same issue once more. Now, when I check `/etc/sysctl.conf` the fs.file-max settings is still there. But `ulimit -Sn` returns 1024 and `ulimit -Hn` - 1048576. What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem than you on Ubuntu 22.04.  after numerous retries, i just get rid of the snap version of docker and re-install docker and docker-compose using apt-get, and everything goes right.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I did in the end as well.